# CakePHP 3.7.5 Retrive data of a field into the controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I apologize in advance if I am opening a question that may have already been asked, but I don't think I have found any results.

I have a problem with the following CakePHP code portion:

```
$unavailable_resource_ids = $this->Resources->Unavailabilities
    ->find()
    ->select(['resource_id'])
    ->matching('Bookings', function ($q) {
        return $q->where([
            'Bookings.booking_status_id NOT IN ' => [6, 4, 3]
        ]);
    })
    ->where([
        'OR' => [
            [
                'Unavailabilities.start <= :start_date',
                'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL '. $recovery_time .') >= :end_date'
            ],
            [
                'Unavailabilities.start <= :start_date',
                'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL '. $recovery_time .') BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date'
            ],
            [
                'Unavailabilities.start BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date',
                'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL '. $recovery_time .') >= :end_date'
            ],
            [
                'Unavailabilities.start >= :start_date',
                'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL '. $recovery_time .') <= :end_date'
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->bind(':start_date', $start_date_object, 'datetime')
    ->bind(':end_date', $end_date_object, 'datetime');
```

I need to provide the appropriate value to the variable `recovery_time`, which will be extracted from the resources table, however I have not been able to resolve the issue.

Table `resources` column:

```
id, description, model, recovery_time, etc....
```

I need the `recovery_time` value to be inserted into the variable `recovery_time`, which can be 1 day, 1 week etc.

*I got a* **solution**, *i have added a sub query into the INTERVAL, here is the code, maybe can be useful for someone else.*

```
$unavailable_resource_ids = $this->Resources->Unavailabilities
->find()
->select(['resource_id'])
->matching('Bookings', function ($q) {
  return $q->where(['Bookings.booking_status_id NOT IN ' => [6, 4, 3]]);
  })
->where([
  'OR' => [
  ['Unavailabilities.start <= :start_date', 'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end,     INTERVAL (SELECT resources.recovery_time FROM resources WHERE id = Unavailabilities.resource_id) DAY) >= :end_date'],
  ['Unavailabilities.start <= :start_date', 'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL (SELECT resources.recovery_time FROM resources WHERE id = Unavailabilities.resource_id) DAY) BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date'],
  ['Unavailabilities.start BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date', 'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL (SELECT resources.recovery_time FROM resources WHERE id = Unavailabilities.resource_id) DAY )  >= :end_date'],
  ['Unavailabilities.start >= :start_date', 'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL (SELECT resources.recovery_time FROM resources WHERE id = Unavailabilities.resource_id) DAY) <= :end_date']
]
])
->bind(':start_date', $start_date_object, 'datetime')
->bind(':end_date', $end_date_object, 'datetime');`
```

Comment: So, the code you've shown is exactly how you need to use the `$recovery_time` variable, and what you're not sure of is how to set that variable? If that's the case, then none of the code you've shown is useful to solving the problem. Or do you need to use the `recovery_time` column from the database directly in the query, so that it uses the specific value for each resource when deciding whether that resource matches?

Comment: I need to use the recovery_time column directly in the query, in order to get the specific value of recovery_time for each resource. But i've tryed to use this: 
    'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL Resources.recovery_time)
But mysql interprets what is entered as a string and does not retrieve the data

Comment: Is it putting quotes around the `recovery_time` specifically, or the entire `DATE_ADD(...)` part?

Comment: Is not putting the quote, simply It paste inside the string As is, without retrieve data from db

Comment: If you just write it as `'DATE_ADD(Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL Resources.recovery_time) >= :end_date'`, what does the resulting SQL query look like?

Comment: The result is this:
       Unavailabilities.start <= 01 / 04 / 19 00 : 00 
      AND DATE_ADD(
        Unavailabilities.end, INTERVAL Resources.recovery_time
      ) >= 10 / 04 / 19 00 : 00
    )

Comment: And with the above result, i get this: 

"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') >= '2019-04-10 00:00:00') OR (Unavailabilities.start <= '2019-04-01 00:00:00' ' at line 1",

Comment: Weird that the bit of SQL you show a) doesn't have quotes around the date values and b) has them formatted strangely, when the error message has neither of these issues. Are you sure that these two are coming from the same query?

Comment: I got a solution, i will post it, maybe can be useful for other peoples, thanks for your help!